# Some friends are happier than others

Tags: wordplay, knowledge, movies

I have six friends whose favorite movies are inspired by our shared hobby.

- The first enjoys an action remake about a man with a licence to kill.
- The second prefers an epic about a traitor leading a medieval revolution.
- The third's is a series of films about a seafaring trickster.
- The fourth's stars the lead actor from the third's, but it wasn't well received.
- The fifth loves a classic underdog story with a memorable training montage.
- The sixth features a blue collar astrophysicist with higher ambitions.
- My favorite movie stars an infamous actor, a puzzler like yourselves, hunting for a fortune centuries old.

What common interest do my friends and I share?

Hint 1:

> All of my friends live in the United States; Residents of North America will have an easier time solving than the rest (sorry).

Hint 2:

> My second friend isn't really a Mel Gibson fan; he just as much appreciates a film about a band of lionhearted home appliances.

Comment: Does the answer is obvious once you got the films?

Comment: You could possibly see the connection already (with 4-5 movies correct), but it should become clearer with all seven. I definitely wouldn't say it's obvious; solving the riddle requires some knowledge of the hobby. I'll also add that I could have even more friends with their favorite movies, so don't get hung up on the number seven.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You and your friends are

> Baseball fans!

Each of the movies is a reference to

> A baseball team name

Here's the list:

> 1. Casino Royale (Kansas City Royals)
> 2. Braveheart or Brave Little Toaster (Atlanta Braves)
> 3. Pirates of the Caribbean (Pittsburgh Pirates)
> 4. Lone Ranger (Texas Rangers)
> 5. Rocky (Colorado Rockies)
> 6. Astronaut Farmer (Houston Astros)
> 7. National Treasure (Washington Nationals)

Personally I'm a fan of the Hunt for Red October!

Thanks to TroyAndAbed and other commenters for most of the movie names!

Comment: Nice ! Quite hard if you are not living in the US.

Comment: Yeah, I could see that. Also, now I understand why "some friends are happier than others".

Comment: Excellent! The Hunt for Red October was going to be a major hint if this went unsolved (as a friend's favorite movie and a popular pun made about the MLB postseason.) I personally like the Skeleton Twins. :-)

Comment: @Roland I guess "Angels in the Outfield" would have been a bit too on the nose. =P

Answer (score 4):

A partial list of the movies:

> 1-James Bond - Casino Royal  (only remake with the same name. Credit to [Player One](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/13197/player-one)) 
>  2-Braveheart 
>  3-Pirates of the Caribbean 
>  4-(?) 
>  5-Karate Kid or Rocky 
>  6-The Astronaut Farmer 
>  7-National Treasure (with Nicolas Cage as the infamous actor)

Comment: I don't believe Licence to Kill has been remade. If there is indeed a remake, I should refine the first clue.

Comment: 5 could also be Rocky. And 6 might be Interstellar

Comment: I think the only two Bond remakes are Never Say Never Again (a remake of Thunderball), and Casino Royale (a remake of the spoof movie with the same name)

Comment: Hans zimmer is a prolific musician... but I dont think it fits all of them.

Comment: Clue 4 refers to Clue 3.


Clue 6 refers to a character whose IMDb description is strikingly similar to McConaughey's character in Interstellar. This is not, however, the correct movie. Perhaps if I had gotten around to seeing Interstellar, I would haven noticed the ambiguity; my apologies.

Comment: 4 could be the expendables

Comment: @A.D. No, clue 4 refers to clue 3, so maybe a Pirates of the Caribbean who was not so great

Comment: My first thought for 6 was October Sky. And if clue 4 refers to clue 3 it's probably the fourth Pirates (if that's even the right movie for 3)

Comment: @WilliamKnapp Sounds like it.

Comment: 1. Correct
2. Correct
3. Refers to the series, so don't worry about the specific film
4. A movie with familiar faces to 3, but not part of the series
5. One of those is correct*
6. Rockets are built by the main character in this film, but not October Sky
7. Correct

*You don't need to know which to solve the puzzle, but once the puzzle is solved, it will be obvious which is correct.

Comment: The astronaut farmer I believe for 6.

Comment: The Astronaut Farmer is correct